# How to get List & Hierarchy of Linked and sub-linked Revit files

Tags: hyperlink, revit

We're trying to get the list and hierarchy of all linked external files. Right now we tried the following code:

```
FilteredElementCollector collectorI = new FilteredElementCollector(DocChild);
IList<Element> elemsI = collectorI.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_RvtLinks).OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkInstance)).ToElements();

foreach (Element eI in elemsI)
{
    if (eI is RevitLinkInstance)
    {
        RevitLinkInstance InstanceType = eI as RevitLinkInstance;
        RevitLinkType type = DocChild.GetElement(InstanceType.GetTypeId()) as RevitLinkType;
        TaskDialog.Show("Debug", "IsNestedLink=" + type.IsNestedLink.ToString() + " IsLinked=" + DocChild.IsLinked.ToString());

        if (!type.IsNestedLink)
        {
            TaskDialog.Show("Debug", "Children=" + InstanceType.GetLinkDocument().PathName.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

We succeed to get the list of all linked files but there's no hierarchy. We don't know which file is a children of which parent.

This is the Link structure we're trying to get:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXUAW.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with GetParentId and GetChilds methods to read the hierarchy. Here is a code:

```
public Result Execute(
ExternalCommandData commandData,
ref string message,
ElementSet elements)
{
  // get active document
  Document mainDoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument.Document;

  // prepare to show the results...
  TreeNode mainNode = new TreeNode();
  mainNode.Text = mainDoc.PathName;

  // start by the root links (no parent node)
  FilteredElementCollector coll = new FilteredElementCollector(mainDoc);
  coll.OfClass(typeof(RevitLinkInstance));
  foreach (RevitLinkInstance inst in coll)
  {
    RevitLinkType type = mainDoc.GetElement(inst.GetTypeId()) as RevitLinkType;
    if (type.GetParentId() == ElementId.InvalidElementId)
    {
      TreeNode parentNode = new TreeNode(inst.Name);
      mainNode.Nodes.Add(parentNode);

      GetChilds(mainDoc, type.GetChildIds(), parentNode);
    }
  }

  // show the results in a form
  System.Windows.Forms.Form resultForm = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
  TreeView treeView = new TreeView();
  treeView.Size = resultForm.Size;
  treeView.Anchor |= AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Top;
  treeView.Nodes.Add(mainNode);
  resultForm.Controls.Add(treeView);
  resultForm.ShowDialog();

  return Result.Succeeded;
}

private void GetChilds(Document mainDoc, ICollection<ElementId> ids,
                        TreeNode parentNode)
{
  foreach (ElementId id in ids)
  {
    // get the child information
    RevitLinkType type = mainDoc.GetElement(id) as RevitLinkType;

    TreeNode subNode = new TreeNode(type.Name);
    parentNode.Nodes.Add(subNode);

    // then go to the next level
    GetChilds(mainDoc, type.GetChildIds(), subNode);
  }
}
```

And the result should look like:

[image]

Original [source](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/aec/2015/12/reading-revit-links-hierarchy.html) blog post.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It helped foxing a big part of my problem but I just have a remaining issue which is: how to get the full path name of all instances. In some cases the same file is re-used two time in the Revit Link Hierarchy. Regards

Comment: for that you need the PathName of the Document object from the linked file. It should work

Comment: Sorry, but in RevitLinkType cannot access to pathname only name. And in sub-assembly AttachmentType is always overlay..

Comment: i do not know whether there has been any improvement in this area in the last year or two. in previous releases, the full path was not provided anywhere by the Revit API. you can use the following workaround: 1. ensure that you have a list of well defined root nodes under which all your links are located. 2. ensure that the linked file name is unique. 3. use the operating system file system functionality to recursively search for and find the target file path based on its filename.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the great answer. It helped foxing a big part of my problem but I just have a remaining issue which is: how to get the full path name of all instances. In some cases the same file is re-used two time in the Revit Link Hierarchy.
Regards

Comment: this is a new question, not an answer.